# AngularJS $locationProvider.html5mode() undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use angular's $locationProvider.html5mode() to removed the "#" in URLs, but for some reason it always throws an error that html5mode is undefined. I tried logging $locationProvider in the console to inspect its properties and html5mode is present but when I try invoking it, it throws an error that its undefined. Has anyone experience this before and wouldn't mind shedding some light on what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['appControllers', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5mode(true);        

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'PageController'
        })
        .when('/app', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/app.html',
            controller: 'PageController'
        });

}]);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You typed incorrect method name. Change

```
$locationProvider.html5mode(true);
```

to

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

with `M` uppercase in word `mode`.

Comment: Wow! thank you so much! I knew it was something trivial but important I was missing. Frustration sometimes clouds my thinking. LOL. Thank you again!

Comment: No, problem, sometimes we just need a fresh eye!